# deleting folders with python scripts

Tags: python, file, directory

```
a = '/mnt/task/a'
b = '/mnt/task/b'
```

Under `a` and `b` ,
There are some folders, with names like `201212194546921-6ab-45654545d-5445c`
As you see, the folders' names are made up of things like serial number, and the date when the folder  was generated.
If I want to delete folders which were generated before a point of time, how do I find and delete them
e.g. delete the folders before last week

Can anyone here help me with this?

Comment: checkout the [python os module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#module-os) try something out and update you question with some code when you are stuck

Comment: And try to format your question a bit better.  It's difficult to read.  Cheers.

Comment: Do you want to include sub-folders??

Comment: yes ,I will delete all folders which generate before lask week

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of python modules that can help you do this:
`os.walk(path)` iterates over all the folders on the given path 
`os.path.getctime(fileName)` return the creation date of a file.
`shutil.rmtree(folder)` deletes a folder and its contents

if you put them together, you get something like this:

```
import os
import time
import shutil

for folder ,subFolder, filenames in os.walk('/mnt/task/a'):
    print folder , time.ctime( os.path.getctime(folder) )

    if os.path.getctime(folder) < (time.time() - 60*60*24*7):  
        print 'deleting: ' , folder
        #shutil.rmtree(folder)  
        while subFolder:
            subFolder.pop()
```

**Note** this code deletes folders ,  based only on file creation time!!
You might need more logic besides file date.

Comment: OP wants to use the name of the file, not the creation time of the file, though they serve the same purpose...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folders you want to delete are directly in `a` or `b`:
The following code creates a datetime object for each of the folders, and then uses the difference between the dates to determine which folder to delete.

```
import os, datetime, errno, stat, shutil
a = 
b = 

date = ''
ref = datetime.date(2013,12,20)

def parse_name(fname):
    '''Returns False when unsucessful, datatime.date() when successful'''
    if len(fname) > 9:
        try:
            year = int(fname[:4])
            month = int(fname[4:6])
            day = int(fname[6:8])
            return datetime.date(year, month, day)
        except ValueError,e:
            return False
    else:
        return False

f2remove = []
for dirc in (a,b):
    for item in os.listdir(dirc):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dirc,item)):
            x = parse_name(item)
            if x and (ref - x).days >= 0:
                f2remove.append(os.path.join(dirc,item))

# --- deleting files --- #
for filename in f2remove:
    print 'removing', filename.split('\\')[-1]
    shutil.rmtree(filename)
```